# MediaWiki - BlogPage extension - "Cannot use object of type Comment as array"

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm testing the BlogPage extension with Mediawiki 1.29.0, PHP 5.5.14 and Comments 4.2.1.

Everytime I save a new article I get this fatal error:

[Fri Aug 25 10:19:23.682888 2017] [php5:error] [pid 60677] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:34360] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Comment as array in /usr/local/mediawiki/testwiki/extensions/BlogPage/BlogPageClass.php on line 931, referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php/Speciale:ArticlesHome

The article seems to be saved anyway but when I try to open it I get the same error.

Is perhaps my PHP version too old?

Comment: I found out a workaround: disabling the "comments of the day" feature. I edited the file extensions/BlogPage/extension.json and changed the property "comments_of_day" from true to false. Now it works.

Comment: A version incompatibility between BlogPage and Comment? Would be easier to see if you declared what version of the extensions you are using. (MediaWiki release branch, git commit id etc.)

Comment: From "Special:Version" page:
MediaWiki  1.29.0
BlogPage 2.4.8 (c1e5468)
Comments 4.2.1 (2b8b9d4)

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like programmer error. BlogPage expects an array of arrays but gets an array of Comments; glancing at the history, Comments never worked differently. The bug seems to have been introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-BlogPage/commit/a5477d7cc52223982246e7c18293f3a27af85f76). You should probably contact the author.

Comment: I signaled the bug with no luck so far: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T174135